# array index out of bounds in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a program wherein a user will be prompt on how many inputs to input. I have 3 user inputs in my multi array, if the user will input 1 then only one user input will appear. Otherwise, if the user inputs 2 or 3, then 2 or 3 user inputs will appear. Upon testing my program, it ran, but the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error appeared. I can't seem to find the error in here, I've tried adding extra index on my multi array but I still get the same error.

```
import java.io.*;


public class student {

private int stud_id;
private String stud_prog;
Object ctr1;

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Object stud [][] = {{1,2,3},{"enter name:","enter age:","enter gender:"}};

public void stud() throws NumberFormatException,IOException{

    System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    for (int x = 1; x<=num1;x++){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<num1;){

            System.out.println(stud[x][i]);
            ctr1 =in.readLine();
            i++;

        }

    }

 }



}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////main/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class persontest {

public static void main(String[]args) throws NumberFormatException,IOException{

    student s = new student();
    s.stud();


 }

}
```

Comment: Also, how come `stud()` and `stud variable` both declared simultaneously! Is it surely compiling??

Comment: uhm..I don't understand, what do you mean by both declared simultaneously?

Comment: this `stud` is already declared as an Object and how can you again declare this keyword as a method??? Is this code surely compiling! Also, please accept highest upvoted answer...

Comment: yes it is compiling, I don't understand what's the problem of having the same keyword wherein they are used differently..

Comment: Ohh! Sorry,I checked it myself,it's fine!!! Sorry again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array index starts from 0 and end to length-1

Change:

```
for (int x = 1; x<=num1;x++){
```

To:

```
for (int x = 0; x<num1;x++){
```

---

First check for length of array before iterating

```
if(num1<=stud.length){
    for (int x = 0; x<num1;x++){
         ....
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** Multidimensional array can contains variable no of columns. You should use `stud[row].length` to get the no of columns of any row.

- `stud.length` gives no of rows
- `stud[i].length` gives no of columns of ith row

---

As per comment

> what I mean is that if the user inputs 1 then 1 user attribute will appear, if 2 then 2 and so on...

Is this what are you looking for?

```
String stud[] = { "enter name:", "enter age:", "enter gender:" };

System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
if (num1 <= stud.length) {
    for (int x = 0; x < num1; x++) {
        System.out.println(stud[x]);
        //read input from user
    }
}
```

Comment: This one took away the error, but it took away the functionality of my program too, what I mean is that if the user inputs 1 then 1 user attribute will appear, if 2 then 2 and so on. Thanks btw.

Comment: read last comments of my post and change the logic as per need.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses zero-indexed arrays, meaning that counting starts at 0 (not 1!), 1, 2, 3, 4...

This means that when you attempt to reference array[4], it's actually getting the fifth element in the array (and if it doesn't exist? ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!)

You can fix your for-loops by changing it to look like this; it starts with zero, and goes up to (but not equaling) num1.

```
for(int x = 0; x < num1; x++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int x = 1; x<=num1;x++){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<num1;){

            System.out.println(stud[x][i]);
            ctr1 =in.readLine();
            i++;

        }

    }
```

Here it will run in two for loop. first one start from 1 to num1. but in next iteration invoking `stud[x][i]` x will be 2 . but stud has index 0,1 only.  Please check your logic